# WiFi connection can't be established for long time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

If I try to establish a WiFi connection in my company it sometimes takes a very long time (15 minutes). I never face the issue on any other network so it seems to be related to my company network. In case I'm unable to connect I see the following Windows Event Logs:

- `Information: 7021 - Connection telemetry fields and analysis usage (Source Netwtw06)`
- `Warning: 6105 - deauth after EAPOL key exchange sequence (Source Netwtw06)`

Comment: Perhaps too many `802.1...` authentication protocols are possible. What authentication is used with the hotspot?

Comment: How can I check this? Once a connection can be established I see 802.11ac (WPA2-Enterprise - login via username/password to company domain).

Comment: In *Settings > Network & Internet > Change adapter options > Properties of adapter > Configure...*, tabs Authentication and/or Advanced and/or Details. Check whatever you find against the properties of the hotspot.

Comment: Hmm... I checked but I don't really know what to look for... Device stack is `\vwifibus, \Netwtw06, \ACPI, \pci`... could this be improved?

Comment: Look more for authentication methods, bands (5/2.4 Ghz) and wireless mode.

Comment: Did you get this to work in the end?